# IllegalArgumentException when sending Parse Cloud Code with Arguments

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, illegalargumentexception

Im having a problem when sending a Cloud Code Request with parameters as a HashMap. The Funny thing is that if I send a request with empty parameters, it works perfectly fine.
Here is my code for the request (Updated with ishmaelMakitla's answer) :

```
Map<String, Object> par = new HashMap<String, Object>();
par.put("ingredients", new String[]{"hey"});
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("", par, new FunctionCallback() {
  @Override
  public void done(Object o, Throwable throwable) {
    Log.v("28", "" + o);
    Log.v("27", "" + throwable.getMessage());
    for (Object obj : (ArrayList)o) {
      Log.v("29",""+((ParseObject) obj).get("title"));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void done(Object object, ParseException e) {
    Log.v("26", "" + object);
    if (e != null) {
      Log.v("27", "" + e);
    }
    for (Object obj : (ArrayList)object) {
      Log.v("25",""+((ParseObject) obj).get("title"));
    }
  }
});
```

And my Cloud Code Method:

```
Parse.Cloud.define ('getFoo', function (req, res) {
    var arrayIngredients = [];
    arrayIngredients = req.params.ingredients;
    var recepyQuery = new Parse.Query("Foos");
    recepyQuery.find( {
    success: function(result) {
        res.success(result);    
    },
    error: function() {
        res.error("Nothing here");    
    }    
    });
});
```

This code works perfectly, but if i uncomment the par.put(...) part, it gives this error:

```
    com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for ParseObject: class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

This is my error stack:

```
05-30 11:31:26.265 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err: com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for ParseObject: class [Ljava.lang.String;
05-30 11:31:26.265 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:114)
05-30 11:31:26.265 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-30 11:31:26.265 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-30 11:31:26.265 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
05-30 11:31:26.265 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
05-30 11:31:26.265 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 11:31:26.265 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-30 11:31:26.265 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
05-30 11:31:26.265 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for ParseObject: class [Ljava.lang.String;
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseEncoder.encode(ParseEncoder.java:136)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseEncoder.encode(ParseEncoder.java:97)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.<init>(ParseRESTCommand.java:138)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRESTCloudCommand.<init>(ParseRESTCloudCommand.java:22)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRESTCloudCommand.callFunctionCommand(ParseRESTCloudCommand.java:28)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseCloudCodeController.callFunctionInBackground(ParseCloudCodeController.java:28)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseCloud$1.then(ParseCloud.java:64)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseCloud$1.then(ParseCloud.java:60)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:715)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:726)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:818)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:806)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:715)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:690)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:806)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:796)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:830)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground(ParseCloud.java:60)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground(ParseCloud.java:99)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.starter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-30 11:31:26.275 12612-12612/com.parse.starter W/System.err:  ... 7 more
```

Is this a mistake I made or there is an issue with Parse?
Im using Parse Server and Parse's Android SDK 1.13.0

Comment: Try changing your `callFunctionInBackground` to not use Generic type (Object) and instead using `ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getFoo", par, new FunctionCallback(){...}` - give it a try and let me know if this helps.

Comment: I just tried it, and the error is the same... thanks anyway! I jus updated the question with your sugestion

Comment: Must you have two `done` methods? Maybe update your code with the latest code you've got. Also what happens if your `HashMap` explicitly uses string array for value type (instead of `Object`)?

Comment: Yes is mandatory to include the two methods if I use your method. I just tried it with the String[] type as the value type of the Hashmap and the result is the same. (I also tried it with the my main option only, and the result is the same)

Comment: What do you send back as `result`? Could you print the log of your `result`  just before `res.success(result);` - I am wondering if the error has to be with the parameters you send or the response.

Comment: I added a console.log('') to print the params, but if the hashmap has a value, the function is not even called. If the hasmap is empty it prints 'undefined'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113316/discussion-between-ishmaelmakitla-and-kmi).

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla We just encounter the same error. I can pass a single string because our backend takes array of String as value in parameter. Any idea? I passed a HashMap of <String, String[]> or <String, Object>

Comment: @Kmi Any idea with the issue I commented? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the `String[]` in the value, simply pass a `String`, for this you should change your requesting code as follows -

```
Map<String, Object> par = new HashMap<String, Object>();
par.put("ingredients", "someIngredientValue"});
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getFoo", par, new FunctionCallback() {
  @Override
  public void done(Object o, Throwable throwable) {
    Log.v("28", "" + o);
    Log.v("27", "" + throwable.getMessage());
    for (Object obj : (ArrayList)o) {
      Log.v("29",""+((ParseObject) obj).get("title"));
    }
  } 
//the rest of your code ...
```

On the receiving end, you then say `request.params.ingredients` - this should give you 'someIngredientValue'.
I hope this helps.